# multiclass classification with double values and scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I would like to train a programm to give dicts various tags depending on the numeric values they contain - with scikit.
My problem is, that I only seem to understand how to classify text (sentences) or just number variables (and not variables that contain mulitple numbers).

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
# available classes:
# hot, cold, wet, sticky

first_sample = {}
first_sample["temp"] = 30
first_sample["airpressure"] = 104
first_sample["airmoisture"] = 70

second_sample = {}
second_sample["temp"] = 2
second_sample["airpressure"] = 100
second_sample["airmoisture"] = 40

# do this manually X times
train(first_sample, ['sticky', 'hot'])
train(second_sample, ['wet', 'cold'])
train(...)

# then do it on a bunch of data by programme
classify(bunch_of_data)
```

Comment: This would be an example of (in sci-kit terms) of multilabel classification or multi-task classification. This [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) has more info. If a dict must have a label (must be `hot` or `cold`, must be `sticky` or `wet`) then its likely more multi-task classification. If it can have a variable number of labels assigned to it, its likely multi-label classification. Converting the information in the dicts to a data-frame would be the first step in building this sort of classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to train two classifiers and fit them to your data twice. Suppose your data is (you can convert your dicts to a dataframe using `Pandas`):

```
| "temp" | "airpressure" | "airmoisture"| "target1" | "target2" | 
|:------:|:-------------:|:------------:|:---------:|:---------:|
|   30   |      104      |      70      |  'sticky' |   'hot'   |
|   2    |      100      |      40      |    'wet'  |   'cold'  |
|   .    |       .       |       .      |      .    |     .     |
|   .    |       .       |       .      |      .    |     .     |
|   .    |       .       |       .      |      .    |     .     |
```

First, you fit the first classifier (clf1) to all your samples (lets call them X) and first column of your targets `target1` (lets call it y1)

```
clf1.fit(X,y1)
```

and then the second classifier (clf2) on X and second column of your target `target2` (or y2).

```
clf2.fit(X,y2)
```